# Confirmation message box on Page load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, confirmation

I have a requirement to show a confimation for a transaction confirmation.

I have a system to maintain a daily transactions from user. If debitor enters a transaction then the confirmation message should display when creaditor log in to the system. If he confirmed that transaction then only transaction will be succeed. There are multiple transactions for a single user. So for each transaction creaditor have to show confirmation msg with that transaction details.

How I will do this in asp.net

Should I call web method from javascript to get all
pending transaction or Is there any other suitable way to do this?

## edited

```
 $(function () {

            PageMethods.getPandingTransaction(onSucess, onError);
            function onSucess(result) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
                    var message = "Please confirm Rs." + result[i].Amount
                   if (confirm(message)) {
                    PageMethods.UpdateTransaction(result[i].TransactionID, true);
                }
                else { PageMethods.UpdateTransaction(result[i].TransactionID, false); }

                }
            }
            function onError(result) { }
        });
```

I am able to show confirm message box. But I want Yes/No buttons instead of Ok/Cancel buttons. So I am using custom dialog box but it is not working for me.

Comment: I have post some code in edited section

Comment: $.alerts.okButton="Yes"; $.alerts.cancelButton="No"; This will not changes my confim message box ok/cancel buttons to yes/no buttons

Answer (score 0):

By javascript you can load confirmation message on page load like this :

```
window.onload=function(){
   var r=confirm("Message");
   if (r==true) {
      alert("OK!");
   }
   else {
      alert("Cancel!");
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

But where to invoke this function ? on body onload in aspx code ?.
I have the same case where i want to perform a operation on page load event of C# with confirmation message (Yes or no), i used this code on body onload but it always run after the code of C# page load event. Confirm message will pop up after operation finished .